# How to read/load yaml parameters with leading zeros as a string?

Tags: yaml, python-3.7, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

How to read/load YAML parameters with leading zeros as a string and manipulate in python 3.7? From a C++ Tool using yaml-cpp(yaml 1.2), I get a text file containing `leading_zero: 00005`. Reading/loading this line of code, seems to be converted into int, but why? Do you know how to handle YAML strings with leading zeros?

## ruamel.yaml (yaml 1.2)

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
inp = "leading_zero: 00005\n"
code = yaml.load(inp)
print(code)
print(code['leading_zero'])
yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

## output ruamel.yaml

```
ordereddict([('leading_zero', 5)])
5
leading_zero: 00005
```

As you can see 00005 is not stored as string '00005' in the ordereddict, but why does `yaml.dump()` show the correct number then?

## pyyaml (yaml 1.1)

```
import yaml
inp = "leading_zero: 00005\n"
code = yaml.load(inp)
print(code)
print(yaml.dump(code, default_flow_style=False))
```

## output pyyaml

```
{'leading_zero': 5}
leading_zero: 5
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there are no YAML strings, there are collections (mappings and sequences) and scalars.
Assuming these scalars are not tagged (as in your case), they can be quoted (for the sake of simplicity this includes literal/folded style) or plain.

In the normal case of loading a YAML document, a quoted scalar will be loaded as strings, and
the plain scalar is open for interpretation as a special type depending on its "content". That 
interpretation could lead to it being a boolean, a date, a floating point value. If none of those match, the plain scalar is loaded as a string.

The normal loading case applies the [Core
Schema](https://yaml.org/spec/spec.html#id2603795).  That schema is a
superset of the JSON schema, and in both plain scalars consisting of
numbers only are supposed to be loaded as [integers](https://yaml.org/spec/spec.html#id2602943).
So this answers your first question on how to handle "YAML strings"

ruamel.yaml, using the default (round-trip)
mode, tries to preserve the specific format your YAML document if you
load, then dump that document (this is not always possible, but it
tries). Although it loads `00005` as an integer, it is actually a
subtype of the integer class, which includes information about the format of
the integer (i.e. including the number of leading zeros). If your 
YAML document is under revision control, it is nice that these kind of things
don't change just because you updated some other part of the document.

This should answer your second question asking why ruamel.yaml shows the correct scalar on output.

PyYAML doesn't do this (and neither does ruamel.yaml if decide to use
`safe` loading). And you are lucky you did try a scalar like `00005`
for your test, because `00008` would load as a string (since PyYAML
uses the pre-2009 YAML 1.1 specification, in which a leading zero
indicates octal, in YAML 1.2 octals start with `0o`) and `00015` loads
in ruamel.yaml as the number `15` and in PyYAML as the number 13:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
import yaml as pyyaml

yaml_str = """\
- 00005    
- 00008    # this is not an octal in YAML 1.1
- 00015
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('ruamel.yaml:', data, type(data[0]))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('-----------')
data = pyyaml.load(yaml_str)
print('pyyaml:     ', data, type(data[0]))
pyyaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

which gives:

```
ruamel.yaml: [5, 8, 15] <class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt'>
- 00005
- 00008    # this is not an octal in YAML 1.1
- 00015
-----------
pyyaml:      [5, '00008', 13] <class 'int'>
- 5
- 00008
- 13
```

Do I know how to handle '"yaml strings" with leading zeros', No I
don't, but I give you you several options to select from, depending on
the purpose with which you load your document (just to be clear: I am
the author of ruamel.yaml).

- In the default, round-trip mode, I load
  them as things that behave like integers, but preserve outer
  appearances specific for the input, as YAML provides an unendless
  number of ways to present any specific number like `5`.
- If you load
  after doing `yaml = YAML(typ='safe')` you will just have plain
  integers, that don't dump with leading zeros.
- If you load after doing `yaml = YAML(typ='base'), you will get the baseloader and every
  scalar loads as a string

As a program:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

for t in ['rt', 'safe', 'base']:   # 'rt' is the default
    data = YAML(typ=t).load("00005")
    dt = type(data)
    print(f'{t:5}  {data!r:7}  {dt}')
```

gives:

```
rt     5        <class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt'>
safe   5        <class 'int'>
base   '00005'  <class 'str'>
```

so if you don't like the magic "integers" of the round-trip mode, load with the base
schema and process the resulting string loaded from the YAML scalar yourself. An alternative
for that would be to unload the integer-matching regular expression from safe or round-trip mode,
but that is more complex.