# Python json scheam validator issue when converting a "number"

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

I have a yml schema defined like below

```
"cost_center":{
         "type":"number",
         "title":"cost center",
         "required":[
            "cost_center"
         ]
      }
```

Now in my yml, file, If I defined cost center as 701 then it works just fine:

```
cost_center: 701
```

but if I defined, cost center as 0701 then it prints 449.

```
cost_center: 0701
```

So, my question is why extra leading ZERO cause different value?

I'm using below ones, to validate my schema against the actual file

```
def validateConfig(configFileName):
        with open(configSchemaFile, 'r') as pub_config_schema_file:
            pubConfigSchema = json.loads(pub_config_schema_file.read())
    
        with open(configFileName, 'r') as pub_config_file:
            pubConfigJson = json.dumps(yaml.load(pub_config_file.read(), Loader=yaml.FullLoader))
            pubConfig = json.loads(pubConfigJson)
        out = {}
    
        try:
            jsonschema.validate(pubConfig, pubConfigSchema)
            out['exit_code'] = 0
            out['config'] = pubConfig
        except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            out['exit_code'] = 1
            out['error'] = e.message
            print(json.dumps(out))
            raise
    
        return json.dumps(out)

response = json.loads(validateConfig(path_to_verify + "config.yml"))
if 'cost_center' in response['config']:
    local_cost_center = response['config']['cost_center']
```

NOw, this local_cost_center gives me 449 if the cost center is 0701 and gives me right value 701 if the cost center is 701 (without 0 in the beginning)

How to fix this error?

Comment: he [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format, which is what you have. The [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006. You are also using a EOL python version and a parser that has not been upgraded to the "new" YAML standard released in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

By prepending a leading 0 to your number, the number is interpreted to be base 8 - not base 10.

```
701 (base 8) = 7*8*8 + 0*8 + 1 = 449 (base 10)
```

Not sure how to fix it though - but if you know the cause, you might be able to find a solution.

From here: [How to read/load yaml parameters with leading zeros as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820256/how-to-read-load-yaml-parameters-with-leading-zeros-as-a-string)

> PyYAML doesn't do this (and neither does ruamel.yaml if decide to use safe loading). And you are lucky you did try a scalar like 00005 for your test, because 00008 would load as a string (since PyYAML uses the **pre-2009 YAML 1.1 specification, in which *a leading zero indicates octal***, in YAML 1.2 octals start with 0o) and 00015 loads in ruamel.yaml as the number 15 and in PyYAML as the number 13:

Comment: Artener, thanks for your explanation. But I don't know how to fix it either? Also I tried to defined schema as string with pattern only number, it shows me jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 701 is not of type 'string'

Comment: Also I tried using ruamel.yaml, this ignore leading zero. so basically don't know.

Comment: @change198. What don't you know? ruamel.yaml does the right thing, so use it.