# Unmarshal YAML file - How to read YAML parameters with leading zeros as a string?

Tags: go, yaml

How to read YAML properties with leading zeros as string without any conversion?

YAML example file:

```
provisioning:
  devices: 
    000000001515:
        properties: 
          example: 30s
        options:
          dummy: true
```

Golang Code - Minimal reproducible example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ghodss/yaml"
)

//DeviceSpec device
type DeviceSpec struct {
    Properties map[string]string `yaml:"properties,omitempty"`
    Options    map[string]string `yaml:"options,omitempty"`
}

//Spec provisi
type Spec struct {
    Provisioning struct {
        Devices map[string]DeviceSpec `yaml:"devices,omitempty"`
    }
}

var input = []byte(`
provisioning:
  devices: 
    000000001515:
        properties: 
          example: 30s
        options:
          dummy: true
`)

func main() {
   config := Spec{}
   if err := yaml.Unmarshal(input, &config); err != nil {
        panic(err)
   }

   for uuid, _ := range config.Provisioning.Devices {
      fmt.Println(uuid)
   }
}
```

Output

```
845
```

Expected Output

```
000000001515
```

Solution

The issue was related to the YAML package I was using `"github.com/ghodss/yaml" v1.0.0`. Replacing it with the `"gopkg.in/yaml.v3"` package fixed the issue and it works just fine - see the comment section bellow - thank you all.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)
```

---

Note: This question is similar to this but this question is using Python: [How to read/load yaml parameters with leading zeros as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820256/how-to-read-load-yaml-parameters-with-leading-zeros-as-a-string)

Comment: The `000000001515` is being interpreted as an octal value: 845

Comment: I tried it and it works as expected, so the problem is somewhere in code you don't show. Please supply a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @fonini In YAML 1.2, octal values must be prefixed with `0o`, you are referring to a rule that was an optional YAML 1.1 extension. In any case this shouldn't happen when the target type is known to be a string.

Comment: [playground link with your code giving the correct output](https://play.golang.org/p/Y9JcL5uFFRo)

Comment: I think flyx solved your issue anyway, the difference in behavior may come from the yaml library : what yaml library are you using ? what version ?

Comment: thank you @flyx the issue was related to the YAML package. I was using "github.com/ghodss/yaml" v1.0.0 (@LeGEC) and I replaced with "gopkg.in/yaml.v3" and it works just fine.

Comment: @flyx Just updated the question with a minimal reproducible example and with the solution for this issue. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we found the error, let's have a post mortem about what happened:

The library you used, [github.com/ghodss/yaml](https://github.com/ghodss/yaml), says that

> this library first converts YAML to JSON using go-yaml and then uses json.Marshal and json.Unmarshal to convert to or from the struct.

It doesn't particularly help that the linked blog post about why this would be a good idea vanished. Anyway, let's see what the code there [actually does](https://github.com/ghodss/yaml/blob/master/yaml.go#L126):

```golang
var yamlObj interface{}
err := yamlUnmarshal(y, &yamlObj)
```

So it takes your YAML input and loads it into an interface. This as a *bad* idea when you actually supply the target type. What happens here is that go-yaml is free to choose the target types, and if it is, it apparently reads in numbers with leading zeros as octal numbers. This is in line with the outdated definition of the [!!int tag for YAML 1.1](https://yaml.org/type/int.html):

```
[-+]?0[0-7_]+ # (base 8)
```

However, that has long been superseded by [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071):

```
 0o [0-7]+   tag:yaml.org,2002:int (Base 8)
```

go-yaml seems to implement the YAML 1.1 rule. This seems a bad decision and may have been done accidentally, possibly warranting an issue report.

So anyway, when the YAML gets loaded, the value gets interpreted as octal value. github.com/ghodss/yaml proceeds to mangle the value into JSON and then unmarshal it again, but we've already lost.

The takeaway is that I would consider github.com/ghodss/yaml harmful and advise not to use it.