# Parse byte array for yaml value - kubebuilder

Tags: json, go, kubernetes, yaml

We are using [kubebuilder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder) to build our custom controller, the problem is we are not able to parse **raw data** as it comes empty when you apply the file.

I’ve created very minimal example which describe the issue.

apiVersion: mygroup.test.com/v1alpha1

```
kind: Rawtest
metadata:
  name: rawtest-sample
spec:
  system:
    type: test
    provider:
      type: aws
      infrastructureConfig:
        kind: InfrastructureConfig
        apiVersion: v1alpha1
        networks:
          vpc:
            cidr: aaa
          zones:
            - name: abc
              internal: 123
      workers:
        - name: myworker
          machine:
            type: "mt"
            image:
              name: name1
              version: "2"
          maximum: 2
          minimum: 1
          maxUnavailable: 0
          volume:
            type: a1
            size: 20Gi
          zones:
            - zone1
```

In runtime I was able to get the the `spec.system.type` value=test and `spec.system.provider.type` value="aws", however I wasn’t able to get all the data under the `infrastructureConfig:` (line 10)  any idea how can I overcome this ?

I’ve created this very simple project to demonstrate the issue ,
See the api/type folder,  after getting the reconcile object (after apply the config/sample/ file ,you see that the `infrastructureconfig` and all related data are

https://github.com/JennyMet/

Here is the code which is trying to read the raw value
https://github.com/JennyMet/kuberaw/blob/master/controllers/rawtest_controller.go#L57

`&rawtest` should contain all the data

please see the type
https://github.com/JennyMet/kuberaw/blob/master/api/v1alpha1/rawtest_types.go#L32

**raw type**
https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/bf32324d9d1a366d8a0a7514956dc39c2f22f7b7/pkg/apis/core/v1beta1/types_shoot.go#L945

https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/bf32324d9d1a366d8a0a7514956dc39c2f22f7b7/pkg/apis/core/types_shoot.go#L774

https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/bf32324d9d1a366d8a0a7514956dc39c2f22f7b7/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/types.go#L94:6

I need a way to make it work in the kubebuilder, as while I apply the file I dont get the values in debug ...

debug pic

[image]

if something is missing please let me know.

Comment: The link to the raw type seems wrong; you are importing v1beta1 so [this should be the correct link](https://github.com/gardener/gardener/blob/bf32324d9d1a366d8a0a7514956dc39c2f22f7b7/pkg/apis/core/v1beta1/types_shoot.go#L945). I don't know enough about kubernetes to really write an answer, but I *suspect* the problem revolves around go-yaml expecting the field fully lower-cased, i.e. `infrastructureconfig` instead of `infrastructureConfig`. The `json:` attribute is ignored when loading YAML.

Comment: @flyx - thanks! , when I've change it to lower case I got an error  `unknown field "infrastructureconfig" in com.test.mygroup.v1alpha1.Rawtest.spec.system.provider` , should I try something else ?

Comment: Can you link to the code in your project that tries to access the value? I cannot find it and without knowing how you try to access the value I cannot give more advice.

Comment: While sweeping through your `go.sum` I saw that your code is somehow using [ghodss/yaml](https://github.com/ghodss/yaml) for loading YAML. That negates my previous reasoning that `json:` is ignored (however, using that yaml wrapper library has [its own set of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66552497/347964)). Can it be that this YAML is processed in two separate ways with different code paths, where the first leads to the error you show in your comment and the second doesn't use ghodss, thus skipping `infrastructureConfig`?

Comment: The presence of `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` in your `go.sum` implies that *something* is using raw go-yaml since `ghodss/yaml` still works with `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`. But it can also simply be some unrelated dependency.

Comment: @flyx - thanks, this is very simple application which demostrate the issue, I put the link in the question,  see https://github.com/JennyMet/kuberaw/blob/master/controllers/rawtest_controller.go#L57 ,  `&rawtest` should contain all the data, currently it contain all the data except the `InfrastructureConfig` values

Comment: Okay I navigated a bit through the code and it looks like this code path does use `ghodss/yaml` (or rather, [kubernetes' fork](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/yaml)), so casing is not the issue. Seeing the newly added picture, your `InfrastructureConfig` is not empty, instead the `RawExtension` is the issue; as you can see, it has `json:"-"` on both its fields meaning that those will not be serialized. At this point, it's not a YAML issue and therefore I cannot help you further.

Comment: @flyx YAML parsing is working perfectly, you can check it by running the following code locally (build will fail in the playground): https://play.golang.org/p/ZkECH5aemLY

Comment: @Adirio- I've updated the issue in git, let me know if something is missing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did the following

1. visit a site such as https://yaml.to-go.online/ convert the yaml to a go Struct
2. make a struct

   t := AutoGenerated{}
3. I assume that the yaml data is loaded into memory as []byte
4. using "gopkg.in/yaml.v2", Unmarshall the yaml to the struct

   err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
5. the infrastructureconfig field is available as t.Spec.System.Provider.InfrastructureConfig

see https://play.golang.org/p/syx8v7gAmDH

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is that I dont get it in the kube-builder, i get empty array for the `infrastructureconfig` ( when debug ) but are able to get the other values ....is it related to some annotations which I need to put here ?https://github.com/JennyMet/kuberaw/blob/master/api/v1alpha1/rawtest_types.go#L32

Comment: I put a bounty it will be great if you can have a look, thanks!